# MATLAB sub2ind / ind2sub in OpenCV /C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, matlab, opencv, image-processing

Are there any functions in OpenCV which are equal to MATLAB's `sub2ind` and `ind2sub` functions? I need both functions for my C++ app.
If OpenCV lacks of these functions, are there any C++ libs which provide equivalent functionality?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can write them yourself:

```
int sub2ind(const int row,const int col,const int cols,const int rows)
{
   return row*cols+col;
}

void ind2sub(const int sub,const int cols,const int rows,int &row,int &col)
{
   row=sub/cols;
   col=sub%cols;
}
```

Comment: note that MATLAB `sub2ind` and `ind2sub` also work on multi-dimensional arrays (not just 2D matrices). This is less important in OpenCV becuase cv::Mat usually presents those still as 2D arrays but with multiple-channels (slices). See [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#Mat): http://docs.opencv.org/_images/math/29954d8c450a7ef8c777681a299e7e510c5c45e4.png

Comment: @paghdv I don't understand you answer can you please explain, for example i have a = [1 2 3; 4 5 6] and i do sub2ind(size(a),2,2) the answer should be 4

Comment: @Gilad you have to do res=sub2ind(1,1,a.cols,a.rows) .... (I'm guessing that you mean the position [1,1] because the [2,2] doesn't exist ... it's a zero based index). The result is 4

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code for 2D matrix.
I have tested it.

```
cv::Mat Utilities::Sub2Ind(int width, int height, cv::Mat X, cv::Mat Y)
{
    /*sub2ind(size(a), rowsub, colsub)
    sub2ind(size(a), 2     , 3 ) = 6
    a = 1 2 3 ;
    4 5 6
    rowsub + colsub-1 * numberof rows in matrix*/

    std::vector<int> index;
    cv::transpose(Y,Y);
    cv::MatConstIterator_<int> iterX = X.begin<int>(), it_endX = X.end<int>();
    cv::MatConstIterator_<int> iterY = Y.begin<int>(), it_endY = Y.end<int>();
    for (int j = 0; j < X.cols; ++j,++iterX)    
    {
        //running on each col of y matrix
        for (int i =0 ;i < Y.cols; ++i,++iterY )
        {   
            int rowsub = *iterY;
            int colsub = *iterX;
            int res = rowsub + ((colsub-1)*height);
            index.push_back(res);
        }
        int x = 5;
    }   
    cv::Mat M(index) ;
    return M;   
}
```